# How to use view created in swift inside an objective-c++ file?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, objective-c++

I am trying to use `react-native's` new architecture and I have enabled `fabric` for the same. I can use a `view` created in `objective-c++` inside my `typescript` code. But I want to use a `view` created in `swift` with `UIKit` in my objective-c++ file

The documentation on react-native's website is still for the old architecture of using bridge so it does not directly apply in my case. There are pretty significant changes in the new architecture.

Below is the working code for the objective-c++ file

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "RNThubView.h"
    
    #import <react/renderer/components/RNThubViewSpec/ComponentDescriptors.h>
    #import <react/renderer/components/RNThubViewSpec/EventEmitters.h>
    #import <react/renderer/components/RNThubViewSpec/Props.h>
    #import <react/renderer/components/RNThubViewSpec/RCTComponentViewHelpers.h>
    
    #import "RCTFabric/React-RCTFabric-umbrella.h"
    
    
    
    using namespace facebook::react;
    
    @interface RNThubView () <RCTThubViewViewProtocol>
    
    @end
    
    @implementation RNThubView {
      UIView *_view;
      UILabel *_label;
    }
    
    + (ComponentDescriptorProvider)componentDescriptorProvider
    {
      return concreteComponentDescriptorProvider<ThubViewComponentDescriptor>();
    }
    
    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
      if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        static const auto defaultProps = std::make_shared<const ThubViewProps>();
        
        _props = defaultProps;
        
        
        _rnThubView = [[RNThubView alloc] init];
        _view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        
        _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _label.text = @"Initial value";
        [_view addSubview:_label];
        
        _label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
          [_label.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_view.leadingAnchor],
          [_label.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_view.topAnchor],
          [_label.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_view.trailingAnchor],
          [_label.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_view.bottomAnchor],
        ]];
        _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        
        self.contentView = _view;
    
        
      }
      
      return self;
    }
    
    - (void)updateProps:(Props::Shared const &)props oldProps:(Props::Shared const &)oldProps
    {
      const auto &oldViewProps = *std::static_pointer_cast<ThubViewProps const>(_props);
      const auto &newViewProps = *std::static_pointer_cast<ThubViewProps const>(props);
      
      if (oldViewProps.color != newViewProps.color) {
        //    NSString * colorToConvert = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: newViewProps.color.c_str()];
        //    [_view setBackgroundColor:[self hexStringToColor:colorToConvert]];
        //    _view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      }
      
      [super updateProps:props oldProps:oldProps];
    }
    
    Class<RCTComponentViewProtocol> ThubViewCls(void)
    {
      return RNThubView.class;
    }
    
    - hexStringToColor:(NSString *)stringToConvert
    {
      NSString *noHashString = [stringToConvert stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
      NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:noHashString];
      
      unsigned hex;
      if (![stringScanner scanHexInt:&hex]) return nil;
      int r = (hex >> 16) & 0xFF;
      int g = (hex >> 8) & 0xFF;
      int b = (hex) & 0xFF;
      
      return [UIColor colorWithRed:r / 255.0f green:g / 255.0f blue:b / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }
    
    @end
```

Now to use a `view` which is created in `swift` inside my `objective-c++` file, I use the following approach

Created a swift file called `RNThubView`. Following is the code for the same

```
@objcMembers class RNThubView: UIView {
  let btnLogin:UIButton = {
      let btn = UIButton(type:.system)
      btn.backgroundColor = .blue
      btn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
      btn.tintColor = .white
      btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
      btn.clipsToBounds = true
      btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return btn
  }()
  
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(btnLogin)
    addConstraintsToButtonLogin()
  }
  
  func addConstraintsToButtonLogin(){
    btnLogin.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
      btnLogin.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      btnLogin.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
      btnLogin.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }
  
  
}
```

And I updated my objective-c++ file code to the following

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    static const auto defaultProps = std::make_shared<const ThubViewProps>();
    
    _props = defaultProps;
     
    
    _rnThubView = [[RNThubView alloc] init];
    self.contentView = _rnThubView
   .....
......
```

The rest of the code remains mostly the same in the objective-c++ file.

Now when I run via `cli`, the app crashes with no logs on `cli`. When I run via `Xcode`, I get the following logs with a white screen on the simulator

```
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Inspector
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Preferences
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin React
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Network
2022-07-04 19:16:34.262238+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596543] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-04 19:16:34.290263+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596543] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-04 19:16:34.293022+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596537] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C1] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2022-07-04 19:16:34.296327+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596537] TCP Conn 0x600001130370 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2022-07-04 19:16:36.557475+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596543] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-04 19:16:36.558768+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596543] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-04 19:16:36.559075+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596538] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C5] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2022-07-04 19:16:36.559146+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596538] TCP Conn 0x600001104840 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2022-07-04 19:16:36.728528+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596578] [javascript] Running "FabricSwift" with {"fabric":true,"initialProps":{"concurrentRoot":true},"rootTag":1}
2022-07-04 19:16:37.065773+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596539] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C9.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-04 19:16:37.066881+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596539] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C9.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-04 19:16:37.067294+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596539] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C9] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2022-07-04 19:16:37.067425+0530 FabricSwift[51914:596539] TCP Conn 0x6000011370d0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
assertion failed [thread_context != nullptr]: got an exception for an unknown thread
(ExceptionServer.cpp:809 handle_exception)
Message from debugger: Xcode has killed the LLDB RPC server to allow the debugger to detach from your process. You may need to manually terminate your process.
```

The full source is here https://github.com/PritishSawant/ReactNativeFabricSwiftTry => This works but everything is in `objective-c++` and the usage of `swift` is commented out.

https://github.com/PritishSawant/ReactNativeFabricSwiftTry/tree/swift-try => This contains what I have tried doing with `swift` and `objective-c++` code resulting in the above crash which I mentioned

Also how to pass `props` from `objective-c++` to `swift`. In my example it is a `color` prop which once set from the `react-native's` side should use the value in my `swift` file.

Comment: If RNThubView written in swift was supposed to replace RNThubView written in Objective-C then it seems that you did not implement the RCTThubViewViewProtocol protocol in swift version of this view. Or if you try to put swift RNThubView as a subview of objective-c RNThubView in this line "_rnThubView = [[RNThubView alloc] init];" then it seems that you are rather adding objective-c RNThubView inside objective-c RNThubView, it is unclear because you used the same class name.

Comment: @LeszekSzary I though the objective-c++ and swift file name should be same. May be it doesn't matter. RNThubView(swift) is not supposed to replace the one written in Objective-C++. I want to use view written in swift inside my Objective-C++ file. I tried using different names but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time. This is completely possible. You need to include the class type in the header file you are trying to use the code in. Something like this:

```
//
//  SomeVC.h
//  MyProjectApp
//
//  Copyright Something. All rights reserved.
//
    
#import "SomethingNotRelated1.h"
#import "SomethingNotRelated2.h"
#import "SomethingNotRelated3.h"

#define DEFAULT_SOMETHING_NOT_RELATED_TEXT NSLocalizedString(@"Insert SOMETHING RANDOM...", nil)

@class SomeRandomKeyboardView; //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE. DO IT LIKE THIS.
```

and the class

```
@objcMembers class SomeRandomKeyboardView: UIToolbar { //FOR THIS CLASS
...
}
```

Comment: Does not work. I get same issue. Can you submit a PR to my repo

Comment: Hmm not sure what your issue is then. I just pulled your repo and tried it and it compiled for me.

Comment: yes that works because I have commented the swift code in objective-c++ file. Try uncommenting the swift code and comment out the objective-c++ code. Try this branch https://github.com/PritishSawant/ReactNativeFabricSwiftTry/tree/swift-try where I have tried with swift code